# Custom states in Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015 for reporting

Tags: tfs, sprint

So basically, at my workplace we are going to be changing the regular "states" that are in the agile iterations/sprints in Team Foundation Server 2015. We are going from the states "New, Active, Closed" to "New, Coding, Testing, UAT, Done". The WIT for tasks will be edited to reflect the new workflow, and the process config file will be edited to reflect the new states that we are adding/editing. My question is, are the new states that I've added going to be in the reporting automatically? Or, is/are there other step/steps that have to be done for the new states to be included in reporting?

Just wanted some input from others that have done custom states in their iterations for tasks as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the States will be in the Reporting. Have you considered using the Kanban customisation before you start changing states? Kanban columns are also reportable, and are much easier customisations to make than the WI Type Definitions. Also, you can create a new temporary Team Project / Collection to test these things if you're ever unsure.

Comment: Okay great, thank you! Yeah I've seen the new Kanban customization feature in TFS 2015, and it does look pretty nice. However, I'm supposed to do it in the iterations/sprints for work purposes as it is what I was told to do.

Comment: Which report do you want to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried to customized a State "Verify", manually processed the Warehouse and AnalysisDatabase, and checked in the PivotTable in Excel (Selected workitem State and Reason), the custom State sat there as expected:

[image]

So, if the process of customizing State is correct, you'll have it in Report without customizing Reports.